# Не могу сделать полный цикл

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализована желтая бегущая полоска на [guidants.com](http://guidants.com).

Сделала так:

1) В css добавила стили:

```
#advertising1 { padding: 2px 0px 1px 0px; }
#advertising { width: 1px; height: 1px; background:#ffcc00; }
```

2) Создала файл advertising.js, в него добавила код:

```
jQuery(function($){
    var doc = $(document);
    doc.find('#advertising').animate({ width: '100%'}, 7000);
});
```

3) В место где дожна быть бегущая штучка добавила:

```
<div id="advertising1"><div id="advertising"></div></div>
```

Результат на [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxEY9/).

Полоска появилась, при заходе на сайт, также как и на guidants.com начинает двигаться слева направо, только вот делает один цикл и остается в конце экрана, т.е. растягиватся на всю ширину сайта.

Как сделать, чтобы полоска возвращалась назад и начинала новый цикл ?

Comment: Дорогая Марта, залейте код на jsfiddle.com чтобы было удобнее вам помочь!

Comment: почему плохо ? работает же.

Answer (score 2):

делал сам аналогичную вешь

**css:**

```
#loader { 
width:100%; 
height:5px; 
margin:0px; 
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 95px;
```

}

```
.fullwidth .expand { 
    width:100%; 
    height:3px; 
    margin:2px 0; 
    background:#c80370; 
    position:absolute;
    -moz-animation:fullexpand 3s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation:fullexpand 3s ease-out;
    animation:fullexpand 3s ease-out;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes fullexpand {
    0%  { width:0px;}
    100%{ width:100%;}  
}
@-webkit-keyframes fullexpand {
    0%  { width:0px;}
    100%{ width:100%;}  
}
```

**html:**

```
<div id="loader" class="fullwidth">
  <span class="expand"></span>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
function startLoader() {
    $('#loader').removeClass('fullwidth').delay(10).queue(function(next){
        $(this).addClass('fullwidth');
        next();
    });
}

function stopLoader() {
    $('#loader').removeClass('fullwidth');
}
```

Comment: eicto пишет "вам плохо подсказали. :) тот кто это писал не знает js "

а что не так с кодом ? работает же, ваш код напротив,не работает

Comment: @Marta поэтому я и говорю вам, имейте совесть платите деньги тем кто вам пишет код. Т.к. вы пытаетесь программировать не понимая даже как скопипастить код правильно.

Comment: ну так это же не платный сайт, написано "задать вопрос" , я и задала :)

у меня браузер такой, копипастить со стилями, последня opera 16

Comment: смените браузер. причем тут платность сайта ? вы понимаете что у вас совести нет ? тут люди помогают друг другу программировать а не программируют забесплатно. почувствуйте разницу.

Answer (score 1):

Надо зациклить её, например функцией окончания:

так чтобы двигалась туда-обратно

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $adv=$('#advertising')
    adv_animate();
    function adv_animate() {
        var twidth=$adv.width()>1?1:"100%"; //выбрать вперед или назад
         $adv.finish().animate({ width: twidth}, 7000,adv_animate); //как только закончится, выполнится по новой
    }    
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/VDDjW/)

так - чтобы просто повторялась:

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $adv=$('#advertising')
    adv_animate();
    function adv_animate() {
        var twidth="100%"; 
         $adv.css({width: 0}).animate({ width: twidth}, 7000,adv_animate); //как только закончится, выполнится по новой
    }    
});
```

[демо](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/VDDjW/4/)

В следующий раз пожалуйста внимательнее оформляйте вопрос, а-то у вас там была даже копипаста с редактора.

Comment: не работает, полоска вообще не двигается.

Comment: перепроверьте, я там пару раз опечатался. (и только что сделал что-бы она возвращалась :))

Comment: странно,скопировала ваш код, у меня не работает.


и в вашем примере полоска доходит до конца,затем двигается обратно, на guidants.com доходит до конца и заново начинается с начала экрана.

Comment: я наверное не понял что вы хотели. насчет не работает - надо больше диагностики  - вывод с консоли и прочее.

Comment: так работает

Comment: и чем это отличается от моего кода ? кроме названия функции ?

Answer (score 0):

Вот подсказали на одном форуме:

```
jQuery(function($){
   function hr() {

  $('#advertising').animate({width: '100%'}, 7000, function () {$(this).css({width: '1px'}); hr()});}; hr(); }

);
```

Comment: @Marta, отметьте свой ответ как "Принятый"

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать setTimeout()
http://jsfiddle.net/xjm36/

Comment: позвольте узнать зачем тут setTimeout когда у animate есть параметр функции выполняемой по завершению ? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/xjm36/3/

Comment: ну можно и так

Comment: Ребята, у меня уже все работает, код я добавила выше.

eicto. ваш код вообще не работает, еще других поучаете..